# AWS Cloudformation modify resolv.conf in EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, dns, aws-cloudformation

I want to add a custom search entry to the /etc/resolv.conf file in my EC2 instances when they start up.

I use Cloudformation to provision my servers. The file is already populated with one search entry by AWS so I just want to add a second entry to this line, like so:

```
search myCompany.com region.compute.internal
```

What is the best way to achieve this using cloudformation?

Answer (score 1):

With the user data parameter: that will do all necessary modifications to your instance at launch time. In your instance definition in the CloudFormation script, add something like this:

```
  MyEC2Instance:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Instance
    Properties:
      UserData:
        Fn::Base64: !Sub |
          #!/bin/bash
          echo "search myCompany.com region.compute.internal" >> /etc/resolv.conf
```

Comment: Problem is that the "region.compute.internal" stuff is coming from AWS, I don't really want to code that in my script

Comment: ouch! Is that a variable that you can pull from source resource in the script? Is is it a variable from another stack that you can export?

Comment: Not that I know of. AWS automatically creates the content of the resolv.conf file. I think all EC2-instances have it

Comment: ahhh Ok, so you want to use the use the aws dns, so what about `${AWS::Region}.compute.internal`? That will automatically get you the region where the stack is deployed

Comment: Yeah,this would work but feels a bit brittle. I'm wondering if there's a more "official" way to do it :)